# Eliminating buffer overflow in freads (C)

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Simply problem, but slightly weird because of requirements.

Basically, I am trying to prevent buffer overflow when I am reading in file use file I/O because I am reading the file with a buffer size of 32. I feel like this should have been answered somewhere, but for the life of me my searching is not turning it up.

A simplified version of my code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>                
#include <string.h>               
#define BUFFER_SIZE 32              
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * read_file;
       
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    read_file = fopen("test.txt","r");
    
    size_t num_rec = BUFFER_SIZE;
    while(fread(buffer, 1,num_rec, read_file) > 0) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    fclose(read_file);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Say I am trying to read a test.txt that has the contents:

```
This is a test file. 
The file is a test. 
I am having an overflow problem.
My C is not the best.
```

I get a output like this:

```
This is a test file.                                                                                                                                                               
The file is a test.                                                                                                                                                                
I am having an overflow problem.                                                                                                                                                   
My C is not the best.w problem.                                                                                                                                                    
My C is not the best
```

I understand that the simplest way of solving this is reading in 1 char at a time not 32, however, is there a way to solve this while still reading in 32 chars at a time?

Comment: `printf` expects a null terminated string, but you never arranged for `buffer` to be null terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`fread()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) function reads binary data and doesn't add null bytes.  You need to tell `printf()` how many bytes to print, which should be the number returned by `fread()`.

```c
size_t nbytes;
while((nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, num_rec, read_file)) > 0)
    printf("%.*s", (int)nbytes, buffer);
```

Note that `fread()` returns a `size_t`, but the `.*` operation in [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) requires an `int`; hence the cast (though it would be possible to save the value from `fread()` in an `int` and use that without the cast).

Answer (score 3):

The following saves the return value of [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) then uses it to [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) the characters that have been read, and no more than that.

```
size_t read_bytes;
while((read_bytes = fread(buffer, 1,num_rec, read_file)) > 0) {
    printf("%.*s", (int)read_bytes, buffer);
}
```

Comment: Remarkably similar to my proposed code.  Great minds think alike, or something.

Comment: I am of the opinion that `printf` doesn't deserve all the bad press that it gets, and this was a chance to show how it *can* be used right ;-)

Comment: Yes.  On the whole, `printf()` is mostly sane enough.  It tends to be `scanf()` that earns people's ire, and that at least somewhat justifiably.  One of the major omissions in `scanf()` is the analogue of `*` in `printf()` — although `scanf()` does support `*`, it has a completely different meaning (suppress assignment, not specify size dynamically).

Comment: Right, and the missing *other* `*` has long been one of my pet peeves about `scanf`.